# How to remotely update Symfony FW applications?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, bundle, symfony5

I have a **reseller hosting** and I create hosting space for my **customers**. All hosting includes the same **PHP applications** written in **Symfony FW**.

Everything is good so far, but there is a point where I get stuck.

How to **remotely update?**
Is there a **bundle** or method for this action? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you want to update Symfony frameworks remotely?
if you like pull-based strategy so you can create an endpoint for yourself and return versioning as a result and set a crontab inside of your hostings to call that endpoint and check if the version has been changed so run composer update Symfony/* in that directory.. or for a push-based strategy you can add endpoints in your Symfony hosting app and call it from outside.